# Select member for comparison in sort or search

Tags: c++, sorting

This code is predicated on the notion that when sorting (or using a sorted collection of items, such as with `std::lower_bound`) you're *usually* comparing a single field in each object being sorted/searched.

So a typical `sort` might look something like:

```
// Sort by age
std::sort(people.begin(), people.end(), 
    [](Person const &a, Person const &b) { return a.age < b.age; });
```

Or:

```
// sort by height, descending:
std::sort(people.begin(), people.end(), 
    [](Person const &a, Person const &b) { return b.height < a.height; });
```

Although the lambda is cleaner than C++98 code, I'd really rather be able to specify something like `by(height, descending)`. I haven't (yet) figured out a way to (quite) get to that ideal, but I think this gets us quite a bit closer:

```
#ifndef SORT_MEMBERS_H_
#define SORT_MEMBERS_H_

namespace sort {
    namespace detail {
        template <class FieldType, class RecordType>
        struct Desc {
            FieldType RecordType::*fn;
        public:
            Desc(FieldType RecordType::*fn) : fn(fn) {}

            bool operator()(RecordType const &a, RecordType const &b) {
                return b.*fn < a.*fn;
            }
        };

        template <class FieldType, class RecordType>
        struct Asc {
            FieldType RecordType::*fn;
        public:
            Asc(FieldType RecordType::*fn) : fn(fn) {}

            bool operator()(RecordType const &a, RecordType const &b) {
                return a.*fn < b.*fn;
            }
        };
    }

    template <class FieldType, class RecordType>
    detail::Asc<FieldType, RecordType> ascending(FieldType RecordType::*b) {
        return detail::Asc<FieldType, RecordType>(b);
    }

    template <class FieldType, class RecordType>
    detail::Desc<FieldType, RecordType> descending(FieldType RecordType::*b) {
        return detail::Desc<FieldType, RecordType>(b);
    }
}

#endif
```

Example usage would be something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "sort_members.h"

struct Person
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    int age;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Person const &person) {
        return os << person.first_name << " " << person.last_name << ", " << person.age;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Person> people = { 
        { "John", "Rambo", 42 }, 
        { "Joffrey", "Baratheon", 14 }, 
        { "Kyle", "Reese", 25 } 
    };

    std::sort(people.begin(), people.end(), sort::descending(&Person::age));

    std::cout << "Sorted by age, descending:\n";
    for (const auto& person : people)
        std::cout << person << "\n";

    std::cout << "\nSorted by last name:\n";
    std::sort(people.begin(), people.end(), sort::ascending(&Person::last_name));
    for (const auto& person : people)
        std::cout << person << "\n";
}
```

I'd welcome any comments--but I'm mostly interested in the part in the header; the file using it is just a demo, not anything very interesting in itself, beyond the fact that it demonstrates how the preceding code is used.

Comment: Use `cppsort::sort(people, &Person::last_name)` of course :p

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit nitpicky, but `Asc` and `Desc` aren't that good of names for classes. Granted, they are in your `detail` namespace, so it should be fine, but why not just write out the names `Ascending` and `Descending`?

I do find `Asc` more ambiguous than `Desc`, because I see "desc" as shorthand for "descending" more often.

---

Both `Desc` and `Asc` are `struct`s, which means that your `public:` is redundant. You probably want to make them `class`es, as it seems you want to hide the `fn` member variable.

---

Why restrict the sort-by function to being by member variables? You could easily let it work for any callable object:

```
template <class F>
class Asc {
    F fn;
public:
    Asc(F fn) : fn(std::move(fn)) {}

    template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    bool operator()(Lhs&& a, Rhs&& b) {
        // by separating the types like this, we gain a little bit
        // of generality. Not that it matters if we are using it
        // with std::sort only. However, really what the overall
        // utility is doing is defining a comparator, so you might
        // want to keep it more general
        return fn(std::forward<Lhs>(a)) < fn(std::forward<Rhs>(b));
    }
};
```

I know that, at this point, this removes the ability to use member functions at all, but we can use [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to remedy that:

```
    template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    bool operator()(Lhs&& a, Rhs&& b) {
        return std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Lhs>(a)) < std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Rhs>(b));
    }
```

Although `std::invoke` does require C++17. If you don't want to require C++17, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32918679/1896169) discusses how to get the behavior of `std::invoke` in C++11. In particular, you can use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
    template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    bool operator()(Lhs&& a, Rhs&& b) {
        return std::ref(fn)(std::forward<Lhs>(a)) < std::ref(fn)(std::forward<Rhs>(b));
    }
```

Although you may want to wrap the `std::ref(callable)(args...)` into a utility function to make the code more self-documenting

---

There's also a small problem, where if the field we are sorting by is a pointer, you can have undefined behavior. [Comparing pointers with `operator<` is only allowed if the pointers are from the same array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099080/1896169). So it would be better to use `std::less`:

```
    template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    bool operator()(Lhs&& a, Rhs&& b) {
        return std::less<>()(std::ref(fn)(std::forward<Lhs>(a)), std::ref(fn)(std::forward<Rhs>(b)));
    }
```

But if you don't have C++14, you'd have to write something like this instead:

```
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(T const& a, T const& b) {
        auto cmp = std::less<
            std::decay_t<decltype(std::ref(fn)(a))>
        >();
        return cmp(std::ref(fn)(a), std::ref(fn)(b));
    }
```

---

Also, we can actually combine both `Asc` and `Desc`. Currently, the only difference is that you call `operator<` with the arguments in the other order.

Instead, what we can do is take a comparator in our class:

```
template <class F, class Compare = std::less<>>
class SortBy {
    F fn;
    Compare cmp;
public:
    SortBy(F fn, Compare cmp = {})
        : fn(std::move(fn))
        , cmp(std::move(cmp))
    {}

    template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    bool operator()(Lhs&& a, Rhs&& b) {
        return cmp(
            std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Lhs>(a)),
            std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Rhs>(b))
        );
    }
};
```

Then, you can reduce your `ascending` and `descending` functions down to a single function:

```
template<typename F, typename Compare = std::less<>>
SortBy<F, Compare> sort_by(F fn, Compare cmp = {}) {
    // by using uniform initialization, we don't have to repeat the
    // type of SortBy<...>
    return { std::move(fn), std::move(cmp) };
}
```

If the user wanted to sort descending, they'd have to use `sort_by(..., std::greater<>)`. That does require that an `operator>` is defined for their type, but they can always define their own comparator that defines a greater-than by using `operator<`

---

Orthogonally, splitting the `Lhs` and `Rhs` arguments for the `operator()` makes our `SortBy` a [transparent comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/1896169), so we should indicate this by adding a `is_transparent` typedef:

```
template <class F, class Compare = std::less<>>
class SortBy {
    F fn;
    Compare cmp;
public:
    using is_transparent = void;

    SortBy(F fn, Compare cmp = {})
        : fn(std::move(fn))
        , cmp(std::move(cmp))
    {}

    template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    bool operator()(Lhs&& a, Rhs&& b) {
        return cmp(
            std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Lhs>(a)),
            std::invoke(fn, std::forward<Rhs>(b))
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Excellent comments/suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: `std::common_type` might help for your remark

Comment: @Jarod42 That part was supposed to be a brief mention. I'm trying to decide if it's worth complicating it rather than leaving it as an "exercise for the reader" like the comment does

Comment: Other possibility is to not provide *transparent* comparer neither (`template LHS, template RHS` -> `template T`) (BTW `is_transparent` `typedef` is missing).

Answer (score 2):

The other reviews are good, but it's possible to create something much closer to the pleasant looking syntax you propose by using a macro.

```
#define byAscending(field, collection) std::sort(\
        collection.begin(), \
        collection.end(), \
        [](decltype(*collection.begin()) &a, decltype(*collection.begin()) &b){\
           return a.field < b.field;\
        })
```

It's a macro, and as such it won't win any beauty contests, but it does make the calling code easy to read and understand:

```
byAscending(age, people);
```

If desired, the macro could be made to encapsulate only the lambda.  That might look like this:

```
#define byAscending(object, field) [](object &a, object &b){\
                                      return a.field < b.field;}
```

Usage of that version looks like this:

```
std::sort(people.begin(), people.end(), byAscending(Person, age));
```

I'm undecided as to whether this is better or worse than the original, but it seemed like a not unreasonable use of a macro.

Answer (score 1):

This utility might have a small performance problem. It is harder for current optimizers to optimize this style of object, with a pointer to member function (PMF) as a data member.

I know this sounds a bit like black magic, but Stephan T. Lavavej claims that using `std::mem_fn` is bad because of poor optimizability in [this CppCon talk](https://youtu.be/zt7ThwVfap0?t=18m40s). Basically, the optimizer can have difficulty seeing that a PMF stored as a data member is actually constant, making it difficult to inline.

However, if you don't store the PMF as a data member, the optimizer has a better time. Thus, it would be more optimizable in general to instead write a `sort_by` function with [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke):

```
namespace sort {
    template <typename Iter, typename F, typename Compare = std::less<>>
    void sort_by(Iter begin, Iter end, F fn, Compare cmp = {}) {
        std::sort(begin, end, [&](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) {
            return cmp(
                std::invoke(fn, std::forward<decltype(lhs)>(lhs)),
                std::invoke(fn, std::forward<decltype(rhs)>(rhs))
            );
        });
    }
}
```

By taking `Compare` as a parameter, we make it so that we don't need two separate utilities for sorting ascending vs descending. The user can specify they want to sort descending by passing in `std::greater<>`.